# ASP MVC Axios post with model

Tags: javascript, asp.net, axios

I'm trying to make an Axios post to my CantSignInForAdmin action to send password reset mails. However, I get server error. If I remove the model from the action, it passes no problem, but the model seems to be a problem.
Here's the request payload:

```
'{Email: "*****@****.****"}
Email: "*****@****.****"'
```

Action:

```
 public ActionResult CantSignInForAdmin(CantSignInModel model)
        { ... }
```

JS:

```
let model = { Email: userName, Message: '', Type: '', CurrentState: '' }
            axios({
                url: `/account/cantsigninforadmin`,
                method: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: { Email: userName }

            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                }).catch(error => {

                    console.log(error);


                });
```

Model:

```
public class CantSignInModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public State CurrentState { get; set; }

        public enum State
        {
            Initial,
            UserNotFound,
            EmailSent,
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to send the whole model in your data object data: model and make sure enumtypes are populated

Comment: {Email: "*****@****.****", Message: "", Type: "", CurrentState: ""}
CurrentState: ""
Email: "*****@****.****"
Message: ""
Type: ""

still doesn't work :/
edit: tried with a string in the enum property but still doesn't work

Comment: I meant when you debug on your controller action

Comment: This is a successful request's "form data" -> Email: asddas@addas.ds
My unsuccessful "form data" is -> 
{"Email":"******","Message":"","Type":"","CurrentState":"Initial"}:

Comment: It doesn't reach the action. Fails before it's called.

Comment: use postman to post and then see if you are hitting the action